# Android RecyclerView and DrawerLayout are overwriting each other

Tags: android, xml

Inside my xml file, I have a recyclerView and a navigation Drawer Layout. The problem is that if I put the code for the Drawer Layout on top of the RecyclerView, the drawer layout shows but the the RecyclerView becomes blank.

If I do the opposite, the RecyclerView is populated, but the the Navigation Drawer is no where to be found. Is this an xml thing? Here is my xml code for this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar" />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/routes_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.findthewayapp.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to move RecyclerView to inside DrawerLayout.

Comment: @HareshChhelana So that one shows both now, but the navigation drawer and my recyclerview are merged into one so it looks weird.

Comment: Check out : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Why are you using a LinearLayout?

Comment: @nigonzalezm I did this so that my Navigation Drawer will be under my customized Action toolbar.

Comment: I think @HareshChhelana comment is the right answer, try also changing `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content` in your RecyclerView, maybe Android is doing some weird stuff with the dimensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we don't use Linear layout for navigation drawer we can use Drawer layout
Remember android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout can have 3 elements only (in exactly this order):

1.Your main Page
2.Left Drawer
3.Right Drawer

use recylerview in fragment_navigation_drawer layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Main Layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Left Drawer -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.findthewayapp.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" /></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```